# Targetting API 28 update

Tags: android, android-api-levels

i have several app with target `SDK 26`, and as everyone know since google applied new rules for play store `SDK` requirements, i have to update my target `SDK` to 28 which involves a lot of updates!

I tried last days to do the update and i faced a lot of errors:

- support libraries conflicts
- gradle conflicts
- 3rd libraries conflicts

So i set everthing back to target `API 26` to do some changes on the app before updating definitely to target `API 28`.

**My question** : what is the best approach / anticipation and the best android studio version i have to work with to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Newest studio (from stable channel) will try to update libraries and gradle to newest version for you. I imagine largest issue you can have if your projects still depend on `android.support` libraries and haven't migrated to `androidx` yet. If you have any specific conflicts preventing you from doing a successful build and haven't found existing answers as to how to update then you can post it explicitly because right now this question is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After facing a several issue as mentioned in the question , i successfully updated `targetSdkVersion` and  `compileSdkVersion` of my projects to `28` , and here i will write all the steps i followed and the changes i did.

- **I - Steps :**

**1 - updating my android studio to the latest version**

**2 - updating my gradle plugin version , gradle version (5.4.1 )**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    .........
}
```

**3 - migration to `androidx` libraries**

**4 - updating all 3rd libraries (Firebase , google play services , Picasso ,.....) to the latest version**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
..........
..........
```

**5 - Updating `google-services` plugin version to the latest version**

```
  dependencies {
    ........
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

**6 - Adding `google()` repository in project gradle**

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    google()
 }
}
```

**7 - Adding Java 8 as `compileOption` in app gradle**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

- **II - Changes :**

For the changes , it really depends on the widgets and the library you are using , but in general some important point should be mentioned :

**1. Enabling requests to all types of connections HTTP and HTTPS**

Add `usesCleartextTraffic` to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext **HTTP**. The default value for apps that target `API` level `27` or lower is `"true"`. Apps that target `API` level `28` or higher default to `"false"`.

**2 - Deprecation and method change**

Some method will be mentioned as deprecated or even not found , so make sure will inspect every line of your code to update or rewrite the suspected method

**3 - Widgets properties deprecation**

As written above ,some widgets could be concerned with the update done before , so make sure to inspect your layout for deprecation or issues

---

***NB:***

If there is something to notice or add here , it would be great . hope it would help someone else in the future .